# Heroku - Unable to install Firebase firestore - Grpc extension issue

Tags: laravel, firebase, heroku, google-cloud-firestore

I am using heroku 20 and wanted to install cloud firestore but getting the error

> google/cloud-firestore v1.27.2 requires ext-grpc

Here is how i am installing package,

```
composer require google/cloud-firestore
```

Does anyone know how to install grpc extension on heroku ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ext-grpc` is not listed among the [PHP extensions available on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support), nor are arbitrary PECL packages supported by the official PHP buildpack.

I found a few attempts at adding support via third-party buildpacks, but don't believe that any of them actually work. If you need `ext-grpc`, you may have to host elsewhere.

Comment: I dont know why heroku keeps these limitations :(

Comment: Would solution from https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-php/issues/3545 work? "Solution is to add this to composer.json:
"provide": { "ext-grpc": "*" }"

Comment: @Eugene, I don't think so. That's the same mechanism that [Heroku recommends for installing PHP extensions](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/php-support#using-optional-extensions), but `ext-grpc` is not listed among the supported extensions. Feel free to try it, though.